# How to use Query Curl on Nodejs

Tags: node.js, curl

**I tried that on Replit:**
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMtFV.png)

but gives that error(On Picture)

I tried that: https://docs.dlive.tv/api/api/query

*Why Didn't work?*

Edit -->
I fixed!
code:
line 11:
JSON.stringify({"query":"query{userByDisplayName(displayname: "POTATO") {username displayname avatar partnerStatus followers{totalCount}}}"})

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/ & https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending formdata while JSON was expected. Send JSON instead: Use `JSON.stringify`, not `querystring.stringify`.

But beyond that, you also have the problem that you are sending a GraphQL query which is, astonishingly, also valid JavaScript (syntax-wise at least) but will not turn into the thing you want once sent. Enclose the GraphQL code in backticks `` ` `` (and remove the `:`s and change the `=` to `:`).

However, using `node-libcurl` for this, let alone in low-level mode, seems awfully and unnecessarily complex for this task. I suggest using something simple like [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios) instead:

```js
const axios = require('axios')

async function main () {
  try {
    const result = await axios.post('https://graphigo.prd.dlive.tv/', {
      query: `
        query {
          userByDisplayName(displayname: "POTATO") {
            username
            displayname
            avatar
            partnerStatus
            followers {
              totalCount
            }
          }
        }    
      `
    })
    
    console.log('Result:', result.data)
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.response) {
      console.error('An error occured! Website returned:', e.response.data)
    } else {
      throw e
    }
  }
}

// This exists just so that we can use the async function
// without unhandled rejections.
main().catch(e => { console.error(e); process.exit(1) })
```

See replit: https://replit.com/@CherryDT/AxiosTest#index.js